# Java I/O - Transactional file storage

Tags: java, file-io, io, filesystems, java-io

I'm looking for a reliable way of storing related files on disk atomically. Either storing all the given files or not storing any file at all. I've come across [Apache commons transaction](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-transaction/index.html), but the project seems to be abandoned due to lack of reliability.
What is the best solution I can get? and how do enterprise systems handle this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to create multiple files over different remote computers or on a single machine locally?

For locally i would do some easy suggestions like precalculating free space, writing temp files and renaming them on success, ... You could store a list of created temp files and their status if the transaction is inprogress, outdated or success. If you ever find outdated from an asynchronous worker you can cleanup those temp files.

For remote machines you need some kind of consistency multicast functions to coordinate your servers in a consistent cluster manner.

Also be aware that databases handle transactions entirely different to clustered business usecase systems, remote file system and shared services e.t.c. (Databases are designed with the ACID principle including transactions whereas shared systems use consistency models with middleware business logic and multicasting groups.)

Comment: Currently it's the single machine scenario and writing temp files seems to be the functionality that the mentioned library offers ("The transactionality is achieved by first writing to temporary files and upon commit moving or copying them to the primary location."). So it means the library can be used in my use case. Is that correct?